# Why is broadcast receiver called twice in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth, android-jetpack-compose

I'm encountering an issue in my Jetpack Compose application where the `ACTION_STATE_CHANGED` broadcast receiver seems to be called twice when the Bluetooth is turned off. I have a composable function BluetoothStateListener that registers a broadcast receiver to listen for changes in the Bluetooth state. However, when I turn off the Bluetooth, the onReceive function of the broadcast receiver is called twice, resulting in unexpected behavior.

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            var isBluetoothEnable by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
            ScreenOne(isBluetoothEnable) { isBluetoothEnable = it }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScreenOne(isBluetoothEnable: Boolean, onBluetoothChange: (Boolean) -> Unit) {
    Text(text = "Hello world isBluetoothEnable $isBluetoothEnable")

    BluetoothStateListener {
        onBluetoothChange(it)
        Log.i("BluetoothStateListener", "isBluetoothEnable $it")
    }
}

@Composable
fun BluetoothStateListener(
    context: Context = LocalContext.current,
    isBluetoothEnable: (Boolean) -> Unit
) {
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        val receiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
            override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
                if (intent?.action == BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED) {
                    val state =
                        intent.getIntExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_STATE, BluetoothAdapter.ERROR)
                    isBluetoothEnable(state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON)
                }
            }
        }
        val filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED)
        context.registerReceiver(receiver, filter)
        onDispose {
            context.unregisterReceiver(receiver)
        }
    }
}
```

In prints log I can see the log function is printing the value

```
2024-02-29 22:44:16.938 15425-15425 BluetoothStateListener  com.example.simplecomposenavigation  I  isBluetoothEnable false
2024-02-29 22:44:17.215 15425-15425 BluetoothStateListener  com.example.simplecomposenavigation  I  isBluetoothEnable true
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are checking if bluetooth is enabled by comparing it's state like: `isBluetoothEnable(state == BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON)`, while there are multiple states:

```
public static final int STATE_OFF = 10;
public static final int STATE_ON = 12;
public static final int STATE_TURNING_OFF = 13;
public static final int STATE_TURNING_ON = 11;
```

If you log the current state, you will get something like:

```
 state = 11
 isBluetoothEnable false
 state = 12
 isBluetoothEnable true
 state = 13
 isBluetoothEnable false
 state = 10
 isBluetoothEnable false
```

Which means you should only check for ON and OFF states like this:

```
when (state) {
    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_OFF -> isBluetoothEnable(false)
    BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON -> isBluetoothEnable(true)
    else -> {}
}
```